# Convert specific country date time to UTC with NodaTime

Tags: c#, nodatime

I would like to convert specific date time value to UTC with NodaTime by giving country code.

For example country is Turkey, country code is TR and specific date time is "Feb 5, 2016 7:45 PM" it would be "Feb 5, 2016 5:45 PM" is it possible?

Also my windows location is not Turkey.

Thank you in advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can't do it just with a country code - you need a time zone. In some countries there are multiple time zones.

Once you have a time zone as a `DateTimeZone` (either via a BCL `TimeZoneInfo` or from the TZDB time zone provider) you would:

- Construct a `LocalDateTime` from the value you've got, e.g. using `LocalDateTimePattern` to parse text
- Call `LocalDateTime.InZoneLeniently` (or similar - more about that in a moment) to get the `ZonedDateTime`
- Use `WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc)` to convert it to a UTC-based `ZonedDateTime`

The part about `InZoneLeniently`, `InZoneStrictly` or `InZone(DateTimeZone, ZoneLocalMappingResolver)` is because a local date and time might occur twice or not at all, around DST transitions. See the [user guide](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/concepts.html) for more details on that.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var text = "Feb 5, 2016 7:45 PM";
        var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Istanbul"];
        var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("MMM d, uuuu h:mm tt");
        var local = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
        var zoned = local.InZoneStrictly(zone);
        var utc = zoned.WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc);
        Console.WriteLine(utc); // 2016-02-05T17:45:00 UTC (+00)
    }
}
```

Now, for finding the time zone from a country code, the TZDB (IANA) database comes with information about time zone locations, which is exposed in Noda Time. For example, if you have an ISO-3166 2-letter country code, you could use:

```
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.TimeZones;
using System.Linq;
...
var code = "TR"; // Turkey
var zoneId = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default.ZoneLocations
                                   .Single(loc => loc.CountryCode == code)
                                   .ZoneId;
var zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[zoneId];
```

The `Single` call will fail if there's more than one zone with the given country code (or none).

If you're going to frequently look up the zones, you might want to build a dictionary:

```
var zonesByCountryCode = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default
   .ZoneLocations
   .GroupBy(loc => loc.CountryCode)
   .Where(g => g.Count() == 1) // Single-zone countries only
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply. But I have only country code and country name not country's city or region data. I don't need to convert country which has got different time zone. For example Greece, Iceland, Turkey, Iran etc. They have only one time zone. is it possible?

Comment: @Kerberos: Basically you need a mapping from country name to time zone ID then. That doesn't exist within Noda Time, but you could hard-code your own.

Comment: I am sorry. I am newbie about time conversion. What does zone Id mean and how can I find zone ID by giving country name?

Comment: @Kerberos: Actually, I've just remembered that we *do* have country information in Noda Time. Will add that.

Comment: @Kerberos: Have a look now.

Comment: Your answer is exactly I am looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: If no problem I would like to ask last question. Can I get other country list which they have different time zone but at same UTC offset. I mean as Argentina. Argentina have more than one timezone but it has got only one UTC (-3) offset according to Wikipedia :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Kerberos: Well it depends on when exactly you mean. I suspect you'll find that the multiple time zones in Argentina have different sets of rules which come into effect at different times - which may be historical, or may be in the future.

Comment: YYYY should be yyyy :)

Comment: @dplante: Probably uuuu in fact. Will fix now.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add a comment to Jon's answer above.

Here's the F# equivalent to the code above using NodaTime 3.0.9 nuget package - notice that I am using yyyy instead of YYYY:

```
let text = "Feb 5, 2016 7:45 PM"
let zone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.["Europe/Istanbul"]
let pattern = NodaTime.Text.LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("MMM d, uuuu h:mm tt");
let local = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
let zoned = local.InZoneStrictly(zone);
let utc = zoned.WithZone(NodaTime.DateTimeZone.Utc);
System.Console.WriteLine(utc); // 2016-02-05T17:45:00 UTC (+00)
```

When I used YYYY I get the message `NodaTime.Text.InvalidPatternException: The character Y is not a format specifier, and should be quoted to act as a literal.`

You can also make the code above less 'letty' as follows

```
let local = ("Feb 5, 2016 7:45 PM" |> ("MMM d, uuuu h:mm tt" |> NodaTime.Text.LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture).Parse).Value;
let utc = NodaTime.DateTimeZone.Utc 
      |> (NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.["Europe/Istanbul"] |> local.InZoneStrictly).WithZone
      |> System.Console.WriteLine
```